# How to change mode audio output in app WebRTC using crosswalk in Android?

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc, cordova-plugins

I'm working on a VoIP app (my app using Cordova Framework and plugin crosswalk), I want my app change audio mode when unplug headphone, I tried using broadcast receiver unplug headphone and using AudioManager.setMode(MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION), but it will be delay about 2 seconds so I want to find another way change direct audio mode in WebRTC.